# Trying to debug a Peer Tutoring Simulation program's logical error

Tags: python, list, class, variables, tuples

Good day everyone-So basically, I was trying to complete a programming assignment but seems like I need some backups.

Here's the 3 files of codes I'm having right now:

```
class Tutor:

  def __init__(self, name, grade, subjects, days, hours = 0.0):
      self.name = name
      self.grade = grade
      self.subjects = subjects
      self.days = days
      self.hours = 0.0

  def get_name(self):
    return self.name
    
  def get_grade(self):
    return self.grade
  
  def get_subjects(self):
    return self.subjects
  
  def get_days(self):
    return self.days
  
  def get_hours(self):
    return self.hours
  
  def add_hours(self, hours = 0.0):
    self.hours += hours
  
  def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    string += self.name
    string += "\nGrade:", self.grade
    string += "\nSubjects:", self.subjects
    string += "\nDays:", self.days
    string += "\nHours:", self.hours
    return string
```

```
class Peer_tutoring:
    """A class to represent and manage NNHS peer tutors"""
    def __init__(self, tuts = None):
        if tuts == None:
            tuts = []
        # a list of Tutor objects, representing all the active peer tutors
        self.tutors = tuts
        self.teacher = "Mrs. Moore"
    
    def add_tutor(self, new_tutor):
        """adds a new Tutor object to the tutor list
        param: new_tutor - a Tutor object"""
        self.tutors.append(new_tutor)

    def remove_tutor(self, tutor):
        """removes a tutor from the tutor list, by name
        param: tutor - a String name of a Tutor"""
        for tut in self.tutors:
            if tut.get_name() == tutor:
                i = self.tutors.index(tut)
                return self.tutors.pop(i)
    
    def find_tutor_subj(self, subj):
        """returns a list of all tutors that tutor in a certain subject
        param: subj - a String subject to search for"""
        tuts = []
        for tut in self.tutors:
            subs = tut.get_subjects()
            if subj in subs:
                    tuts.append(tut)
        return tuts
    
    def find_tutor_day(self, day):
        """returns a list of all tutors that tutor a certain day
        param: day - a String day to search for"""
        tuts = []
        for tut in self.tutors:
            d = tut.get_days()
            if day in d:
                tuts.append(tut)
        return tuts

    def add_hours(self, name, hours):
        """Adds hours to a Tutor object.
        param: name - a String name of a tutor
        param: hours - an int or float number of hours to add"""
        for i in range(len(self.tutors)):
            if self.tutors[i].get_name() == name:
                self.tutors[i].add_hours(hours)

    def display_tutors(self):
        """prints all Tutors in the tutor list"""
        for t in self.tutors:
            print(t)
    
    def __str__(self):
        """Displays information about NNHS Peer Tutoring, including the teacher, number of tutors, and total hours of tutoring"""
        hours = 0
        for t in self.tutors:
            hours += t.get_hours()
        string = "\nNNHS Peer Tutoring" + "\nTeacher: " + self.teacher + "\nNumber of active tutors: " + str(len(self.tutors))
        string += "\nTotal hours tutored: " + str(hours)
        return string
```

```
# main function for the Peer Tutoring App
#   Complete the implementation of this function so the app works as intended.
from peer_tutoring import *
from tutor import *

def main():
  menu = """
        1. Display all tutors
        2. Find a tutor (by subject)
        3. Find a tutor (by day)
        4. Add a tutor
        5. Remove a tutor (by name)
        6. Add tutoring hours
        7. NNHS Tutoring Stats
        0. Exit
    """
  tutor1 = Tutor("Lisa Simpson", 11, ["Band", "Mathematics", "Biology"], ["Monday", "Wednesday"])
  tutor2 = Tutor("Spongebob Squarepants", 9, ["Social Studies", "Art"], ["Wednesday"])
  tutor3 = Tutor("Bender", 12, ["Computer Science", "Mathematics", "Statistics"], ["Wednesday", "Friday"])
  tutor4 = Tutor("April O'Neil", 10, ["Social Studies", "History", "English"], ["Tuesday", "Thursday"])
  tutor5 = Tutor("Mickey Mouse", 9, ["Art", "Science"], ["Monday", "Tuesday"])
  tutor6 = Tutor("Black Panther", 10, ["Mathematics", "Science"], ["Tuesday", "Friday"])
  tutor7 = Tutor("Princess Peach", 12, ["Culinary", "History"], ["Thursday", "Friday"])
  pt = Peer_tutoring("")
    # initialize Peer_tutoring object with initial list of tutors
  nnhs_tutors = Peer_tutoring([tutor1, tutor2, tutor3, tutor4, tutor5, tutor6, tutor7])

    # run the app
  print("\nWelcome to the NNHS Peer Tutoring App!\n")
  choice = "1"
  addsub = []
  newsub = ""
  newgrade = 10
  while choice != "0":
    print(menu)
    choice = input("\nSelect an option: ")
    subjec = ""
    if choice == "1":
      nnhs_tutors.display_tutors()
    elif choice == "2":
      subjec = input("What is the name of the subject you'd like to see available tutors for? ")
      nnhs_tutors.find_tutor_subj(subjec)
    elif choice == "3":
      days = input("What is the day you'd like to see available tutors for? ")
      nnhs_tutors.find_tutor_day(days)
    elif choice == "4":
      newname = input("What is the name of the new tutor? ")
      if newgrade > 8 and newgrade < 13:
        newgrade = input("What is the grade of the new tutor (9-12) ? ")
      elif newgrade <= 8 and newgrade >= 13:
        print("Please enter a number between 9 and 12.")
      while newsub != "":
        newsub = input("Subject to add? (Leaven empty if done) ")
        addsub.append(newsub)
      nnhs_tutors.add_tutor(addsub)
    elif choice == "5":
      removed = input("Which tutor would you like to remove? ")
      nnhs_tutors.remove_tutor(removed)
    elif choice == "6":
      addername = input("Name of tutor to add hours to? ")
      adderhour = input("Numbers of hours to add? ")
      nnhs_tutors.add_hours(addername, adderhour)
    elif choice == "7":
      print("Tutoring status:")
      print("Teacher: " )
      print("Numbers of active tutors: ")
      print("Total hours tutored: ")
    elif choice == "0":
      print("\nThanks for using the NNHS Peer Tutoring App!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I enter 1 while the program is running, it should be displaying all current student's information.

If I enter 2, it should ask me what's the subject you'd like to search. And once I enter it

If I enter 3, it should search by day (from Monday to Friday) and list out the students with matched day/days.

If I enter 4, it should add a tutor by entering their name, grade and subject.

If I enter 5, it should remove a tutor from the tutoring list by entering the name.

If I enter 6, it should ask me who do I want to add tutor hours to and how many hours in total do I want to be added.

If I enter 7, it should display the name of the teacher, numbers of active tutors, and total hours tutored.

Option 1 isn't printing out anything (which is the most basic issue I'm trying to solve) and aside from that option 2 and option 3 is having the same problem. 4, 5, and 6 can't be totally tested out due to the fact that option 1 can't get in work. So, from what I can see now only 7 is working. (Bruh)

Also, there's a problem in option 4: If you didn't enter the number between 9-12 to define new tutor's grade, the message notifying you that you didn't follow the instruction didn't pop up.

Will anyone be willing to give me some instructions?

Edit: There's an error for option 1 which is not being included in the question. My sincere apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Your question didn't include a traceback, but when I ran the code I got:

```
Select an option: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 167, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 134, in main
    nnhs_tutors.display_tutors()
  File "test.py", line 90, in display_tutors
    print(t)
  File "test.py", line 31, in __str__
    string += "\nGrade:", self.grade
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

which points us at one of your `__str__` functions:

```
  def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    string += self.name
    string += "\nGrade:", self.grade
    string += "\nSubjects:", self.subjects
    string += "\nDays:", self.days
    string += "\nHours:", self.hours
    return string
```

As the error says, you can't concatenate (add) a tuple to a str -- an expression like `"\nGrade:", self.grade` is a tuple (of a `str` and an `int`).

I'd suggest doing something like:

```
  def __str__(self):
    return f"""{self.name}
Grade: {self.grade}
Subjects: {self.subjects}
Days: {self.days}
Hours: {self.hours}"""
```

or maybe if you want to get fancy:

```
  def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join(f"{a.title()}: {v}" for a, v in self.__dict__.items())
```

That at least fixes your "option 1" error.  For the other errors, make sure you're looking at the exceptions raised by your code, and then look at the code along with the error message to figure out why your code is producing that error.

Comment: Thank you very much! That actually helped! Now I'll try solving other problems.